# Regex find between words, but don't return the search words

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to grab **Subject** from an email.

This works:

```
preg_match_all('/Subject:(.*?)Date:/', $theEmail, $subjects);
```

But returns like this:

```
"Subject:This is my subject!Date:"
```

I want just **This is my subject!** according to what I've read, that's what I should be getting. What am I missing?

Comment: `$subjects[1][0]` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `subjects[1][0]` to access the value as

```
$theEmail = "Subject:This is my subject!Date:";
preg_match_all('/Subject:(.*?)Date:/', $theEmail, $subjects);

print_r($subjects[1][0]);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/wjgHcP)**

When you use `preg_match_all`, `$subjects` is an array of array containing all the possible matches, but the first match i.e. `$subjects[0][0]` is always the whole string matched irrespective of any capturing group

Comment: Can you please tell me the difference between your answer and mine ? is it the `print_r` instead of `echo` ?!

Comment: @PedroLobito actually I had written the answer in comments. So it took some time to answer here and you beat me to that..I had added some explanation now

Comment: `print_r($subjects[1][0])` and `echo $subjects[1][0]` both return blank

Comment: oh! so I had two matches, the first one was "" - $subjects[1][1] gave me what I was looking for.

Comment: @RandyHall can you explain a bit what you are asking??I am confused

Comment: This appeared in two places in my email text (Subject:...Date:) but the first one had no characters between Subject: and Date:, so $subjects[1][0] was returning that blank string.

Comment: @RandyHall i thought there would be something like that..hope you understood the answer

Answer (score 0):

Another solution other than rock321987's comment is to look `look-around` assertions like this.

**Regex:** `(?<=Subject:)(.*?)(?=Date:)`

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
    $theEmail = "Subject:This is my subject!Date:";
    preg_match_all('/(?<=Subject:)(.*?)(?=Date:)/', $theEmail, $subjects);
    print_r($subjects[0]);
?>
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE0pC7/1)**

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/HktY79)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to output just the capturing group `$subjects[1][0]`, i.e.:

```
$theEmail = "Subject:This is my subject!Date:";
preg_match_all('/Subject:(.*?)Date:/', $theEmail, $subjects);
$theSubject = $subjects[1][0];
echo $theSubject;
//This is my subject!
```

---

**DEMO**

http://ideone.com/ynyidy